# Checking existance through sqlite3 in xcode

Tags: sql, swift, xcode, sqlite, exists

I am using sqlite3 in swift files through the application xcode. I am currently working on a journal project where you log one journal entry a day, and I am storing the contents, date logged etc in a database. Right now I am trying to implement a way to check if a there is already a log existing for a given day. I am using the following query within sqlite3_prepare_v2

```
IF EXISTS
        (
            SELECT *
            FROM journal
            WHERE date = ?)
        )
```

(I am using the ? to later bind a given date btw) How can I check if the evaluation of this query is true or false and set that value to a variable? Will sqlite3_step() return the return values of this query? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
select exists (select 1 from journal where date = ?) as flag
```

This always gives you a scalar result (one row and one column, called `flag`), with a `0`/`1` value that indicates whether at least one record satisfies the condition.

Another option is:

```
select count(*) > 0 as res
from journal
where date = 1
```

Comment: Do you know I can access the return value of the results of this in a swift variable because I want to use this 0/1 return value to influence my swift functions. I am using sqlite btw

Comment: @reillyderrick Something like this: `rowExists = Int(sqlite3_column_int64(statementPointer, 0)) == 1`, since a result of 1 indicates the row exists and a result of 0 indicates it does not exist.